# Правильный вывод процентов

Tags: php

Смотрите, я сделал вывод процентов, но оно выводит примерно так: `2,288727273783`, а мне надо чтобы выводила примерно так: `2,28`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[number_format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

```
$a = 2.288727273783;

echo number_format($a, 2, ','); // 2,29
```

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос еле понял -

используйте функцию `round`

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.round.php

```
$value = round($value, 2)
```

также именно для вывода (а не для округления самого числа) используйте функцию `printf`

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.printf.php

```
printf("%.2f", $value)
```